# ADo repository: The push was rejected because commits contain author email which does not match the policy-specified patterns

Tags: git, azure-devops, git-commit, azure-repos

I'm trying to push commits from my GitHub repository to an ADO repository. The commits in GitHub repository are added by myself and some other authors. On pushing commits to my remote branch in ADO repository, I see this error:

VS403702: The push was rejected because one or more commits contain author email 'xyz@users.noreply.github.com' which does not match the policy-specified patterns.

Is there a way to fix this issue?

Comment: Your repository's email policy doesn't like your email. Change your email, or change the policy.

Comment: In order to introduce third-party commits, the hosting service is supposed to have a configuration item that allows a user to bypass the email verification.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can go to **Project Settings -> Repositories -> Select the repository that you want to push -> Policies -> Repository Policies/Commit author email validation** to check whether its settings conflict with your email address.

The settings may be inherited from the project. Go to **Project Settings -> Repositories -> Policies -> Repository Policies/Commit author email validation** to see the settings for the entire project.

[image: {picture}]

Comment: Thank you! It looks like I don't have the permission to disable this policy. Is there a way to get an exception to push commits from external domains?

Answer (score 18):

Well, in such scenarios **we need to change author email with the authorized email in the commits** for which your repo doesn't allow to push.

```
$ git config user.email yournewemail@example.org
$ git commit --amend --reset-author
```

As pointed out in the below comment. we need to add `--no-edit` at the end.

```
$ git commit --amend --reset-author --no-edit
```

Comment: I had to use --no-edit at the end to get it work for me. ie:
$ git commit --amend --reset-author --no-edit

Answer (score 0):

In my case I Dropped the local commit and checkout to Remote branch, thenafter I merged it with other updated branch and pushed. worked fine

Answer (score -1):

If you do not have access to change the policy you can still commit the code after changing your email in git config:

```
git config user.email "other.mail.mathcing.policy@mail.com"
```

and reset the commits which contains emails that are not allowed, and then commit again with the updated email.